# Would an extra head increase sense range?

Tags: senses

I had this question in my head for a while and I couldn't see question on like it on here. I say this in case I somehow missed it, I truly apologize. I was wondering if a creature would or wouldn't get a boost in sense range from having multiple heads? In this scenario let's use the typical Cerberus, but let's say the brain is in the body and not the heads so we have one place for messages to be sent and not wonder what each head is getting and make the size of a labrador so we have a creature to compare senses to. Would the Cerberus have an increase in hearing and smell or are the heads too close to get any real increase?

Comment: You specifically say increase in range. Do you mean distance? Or angular field of view? Or more directions? It certainly wouldn't increase distance. A person with one eye sees just as far as a person with two eyes. A person with two ears hears over a wider angle than a person with one ear. A person with two heads could certainly see in more directions at the same time than a person with one head.

Comment: This "range" could also be wavelength range of light, or frequency range of sound..  if the heads are perfectly identical it won't add much for these, but suppose ears and eyes in each head  work on their own specialized frequencies, or wave lengths? In that case an additional head could provide some advantages. btw I also wonder what a 2-dimensional scent smells like. Interesting question +1

Comment: double the taste buds/smell receptors = more chances to pick up very small traces of smell, also in case one head had a running nose there is a backup ;D

Answer (score 5):

Probably not.

Close one of your eyes. Can you see any less far? When you reopen your eye do you see further into the distance? Your eyes only see the light that comes into them. More eyes can get you more information, mostly depth, but it does not help you see farther.

Regarding the rest of your senses it doesn't even make sense (pun intended) to sense further away.

You smell the air around you. If a sent is not in the air, regardless of how sensitive your nose is you will be unable to smell it.

You hear the sound that reaches your ears. If a sound doesn't reach your ears, regardless of how sensitive your ears are you will be unable to taste it.

You feel the things that you touch. If a thing is not within arms reach, regardless of how sensitive your skin is you will be unable to touch it.

You taste the contents of your mouth, If a taste isn't in your mouth, regardless of how sensitive your tongue is you will be unable to taste it.

An extra head, with extra, ears, nose, eyes, skin and tongue will not extend the range of your senses.

Comment: You can look two directions at once with two heads.

Comment: @Daron You can touch more things with an extra hand, but your range will still be limited by the length of your arms.

Comment: You are right of course. Reading the question again, I see there is no mention of vision at all! Must have been my imagination.

Answer (score 1):

## [Depth perception, wide field of view](https://www.wired.com/2013/05/bugs-eye-camera/#:%7E:text=Scientists%20have%20built%20a%20digital,on%20objects%20at%20different%20depths.):

Having eyes set widely apart (like on completely different appendages) would allow a couple of advantages.

1. The different views would allow superior depth perception as the different eye positions can be compared and analyzed. So Cerberus might be very good at judging the distance and position of objects.
2. The ability to look in more than one direction and accurately assess the objects in that field of view allows Cerberus to keep an eye on numerous opponents in multiple directions and make it very difficult to surprise.
3. It might help slightly with distance acuity. Cameras using multiple lenses have been designed to take advantage of integrating multiple images and averaging the results with data to determine the likely shape of objects. Insect eyes work in a similar manner, using numerous low-acuity eyes but still managing a relatively good perception of their surroundings. This process of [super-resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super-resolution_imaging) might not be getting enough data from just two or three sets of eyes, but the biggest part of it is in the processing, so your Cerberus would need to devote a fair amount of brain power to analyzing the images it was seeing and combining them in it's head to deduce what it can't otherwise see.
4. There may be some improvement in the ability to stereoscopically detect the [directionality of scent](https://www.npr.org/templates/story/story.php?storyId=6642887). But concrete examples of widely-placed chemoreceptors detecting smell differentially is scant. Most animals manage this trick perfectly well with just two closely positioned nostrils, so any benefit here may be minimal.

Comment: Q: do you think having two noses will help locating the origin of a scent ?

Comment: @Goodies It might, but I can't say I've heard of an organism that uses physically displaced chemoreceptors this way. But that would make a good answer if you can find the example.

Comment: @Goodies Directionality of smell is pretty complex, involving the trigeminal nerves that sense things like "warmth" (spiciness), freshness, coolness, and itching. https://academic.oup.com/chemse/article/34/2/139/421781 and https://academic.oup.com/chemse/article/40/1/61/2908182 and I don't know if pure But in Cerberus, who knows?

Comment: @Goodies Maybe https://www.npr.org/templates/story/story.php?storyId=6642887

Comment: Lovely links! thanks for that.. to find a real life example, it would require some animal that has its nostrils extremely far apart.. would it be e.g. a near-blind predator of some kind, or a night predator.. profiting from a sense of direction, when smelling its prey.. I'll do a search, when I find something I'll put an answer.